# Managing logical constraint to handle concurrency in mySQL database insertion

Tags: mysql, concurrency, semaphore, sql-insert

I'm going to create a booking system. In this system there are some person with limited capacity to meet people in defined period of time. E.g. person A can have meeting with at most 8 person on Sunday between 8:00 to 12:00.

In my database I have two tables about this: `Timings` which show predefined schedules and `Bookings` which shows bookings which fixed.
These tables are defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Timings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `day` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `end_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `capacity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `personFK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_person_timing` (`personFK`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci  AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `booking_code` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `timingFK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_booking_timing` (`timingFK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

So when I'm going to book a new meeting, I should check if number of rows in `Bookings` table related to a specified timing is less than its capacity to allow new booking.

This is a necessary condition but it is not sufficient when concurrency happens.
I mean if I check `count of (timings where timingFK=XXX)< timing.capacity`, for the last available booking, it may happen two people be allowed to book at same time because when they where checking the condition the last booking was still available. I want to know how can I implement semaphore-like thing to avoid two people book the last left position during inserting of new booking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For maximum safety use a transaction + [select for update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

> For index records the search encounters, SELECT ... FOR UPDATE locks
>   the rows and any associated index entries, the same as if you issued
>   an UPDATE statement for those rows. Other transactions are blocked
>   from updating those rows, from doing SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE, or
>   from reading the data in certain transaction isolation levels.
>   Consistent reads ignore any locks set on the records that exist in the
>   read view. (Old versions of a record cannot be locked; they are
>   reconstructed by applying undo logs on an in-memory copy of the
>   record.)

So you might have

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bookings WHERE somecondition FOR UPDATE
INSERT INTO timings ...
UPDATE Bookings ....
COMMIT;
```